# Oracle 11g - Format custom timezone to a oracle valid timezone

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am changing the postgres db backend to an oracle 11.4.0.2 backend. In postgres, I am working with joda datetime with time zone offset and thus resulting in having two columns. One column is the timestamp and the second column is the timezone offset column which is from type varchar.

The database schema is automatically generated by hibernate and when I generate a database record it writes the following entry for the timezone column

```
'Europe/Zurich{+02:00}'
```

This results in a wrong database query if the following "where-sql-query" is being executed:

```
from_tz(to_timestamp('08/08/2016 00:00:00.000000', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff'), 'Europe/Zurich{+02:00}')
```

However, the following slightly changed queries are valid

```
from_tz(to_timestamp('08/08/2016 00:00:00.000000', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff'), 'Europe/Zurich')
```

and

```
from_tz(to_timestamp('08/08/2016 00:00:00.000000', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff'), '+02:00')
```

Is there a proper way to convert the timezone directly in a query without doing workarounds such as substringing the timezone entry in order to retrieve only the +02:00?

P.S. I have to work with timezone information separately and cannot choose a different datetime with timezone datatype

Comment: Note "Europe/Zurich" is different than "CET". The first consider daylight saving time the later one not.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: What are you trying to convert the value to? UTC? And what is actually in your TZ columns, the `CTE{+02:00}` you showed first, or the `Europe/Zurich{+02:00}` in your first query? Is the TZ string always the same; or is part of it always the same? A more complete example might be helpful, with any actual TZ values you have stored, and the result you're trying to achieve for those.